# Read a few megabytes from a BLOB in Oracle

Tags: oracle, blob

I wish to extract a sub-BLOB (a few MBs) from a BLOB in Oracle.

The question *["read first 1kb of a blob from oracle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800294/read-first-1kb-of-a-blob-from-oracle)* doesn't help me, since I need to get more bytes than `DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR` can give me (it returns RAW, which supports only a few thousand bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Use DBMS_LOB.READ(lob_loc, amount, offset, buffer)