# ORACLE ora-22992 when getting a VARCHAR2(1024) from DB Linked database

Tags: oracle

I have a remotely linked DB and I'm trying to get some data.  The main table does have a CLOB field, but I'm not getting it.  I'm linking to another table with a assorted fields, the largest being VARCHAR2(1024).  If I query the data, it works fine.

If I try to pull the data and put it in a staging table, it gives me the error ORA-22992: cannot use LOB locations selected from remote tables.

I'm not selecting it!  And it seems to be related to the linked table, since my insert works if I only get data from the main table.  Is VARCHAR2(1024) considered a LOB?

I don't have access to the database, except through the link, but if I query ALL_TAB_COLUMNS for that table, getting the first 3 fields, they are

```
LOCATION    VARCHAR2(400)
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR2(400)
TYPE        VARCHAR2(64)
```

So my first query is something like

```
INSERT INTO stg_loc (
    location
   ,description
   ,type 
    )
SELECT loc.location
   , loc.description
   , loc.type
FROM locations@remotelink loc
;
```

That works.  But if I modify it to

```
INSERT INTO stg_loc (
    location
   ,description
   ,type
   ,type_descr
    )
SELECT loc.location
   , loc.description
   , loc.type
   , lkup.description type_descr
FROM locations@remotelink loc
LEFT JOIN loc_lkup@remotelink lkup
  ON lkup.lkupid = 'LOCTYPE'
 AND lkup.value = loc.type
;
```

Then I get the error.

The fields in the loc_lkup table that I am using are

```
 LKUPID       VARCHAR2(72)
 VALUE        VARCHAR2(200)
 DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR2(1024)
```

If I just do the query part of the second piece of code, it works.  I updated my staging table so my description field is also 1024.  I've tried using a SUBSTR and only getting a few hundred chars, but since it somehow thinks there is a clob there, that doesn't work either.

I tried the code here ([read first 1kb of a blob from oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800294/read-first-1kb-of-a-blob-from-oracle)), but since I only want 1024 (or less), it's not a clob now.  Right?  If it says VARCHAR2(1024), it's not a CLOB, is it?

This question ([Is it possible to read a CLOB from a remote Oracle database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594449/is-it-possible-to-read-a-clob-from-a-remote-oracle-database)) implies that even if it were a CLOB, I should be able to get the first 4000 chars.  Which I don't want, as it isn't that large.

Or, is this error a red herring, and there is something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It was a red herring, and the CLOB that was causing the problem was in the first table.  Even though I was not selecting that field at all, I was not able to link to other tables with it there.

The solution, which feels ugly, was to create a view on just the original table, excluding the CLOB, and then querying from the view.

So something like this:

```
Create view loc_vw as
   SELECT loc.location
        , loc.description
        , loc.type
   FROM locations@remotelink loc;
```

And then, my query with links would use the view:

```
INSERT INTO stg_loc (
      location
     ,description
     ,type
     ,type_descr
      )
SELECT loc.location
     , loc.description
     , loc.type
     , lkup.description type_descr
 FROM loc_vw loc  -- query from view to avoid CLOB
 LEFT JOIN loc_lkup@remotelink lkup
    ON lkup.lkupid = 'LOCTYPE'
   AND lkup.value = loc.type
```

;

If there is a better solution, I'm still open to ideas.